# C# - List of generic classes

Tags: c#

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Section
{

}

public class Section<T> : Section where T : new()
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public bool IsFocused { get; set; }

    private T sectionData;

    public T SectionData 
    { 
        get => sectionData == null ? sectionData = new T() : sectionData; 
        set => sectionData = value; 
    }
}

public class SectionHeaderData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }
}

public class SectionParagraphData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create sections and store in `List<>` like so:

```
Section<SectionHeaderData> sectionHeader = new Section<SectionHeaderData>();
sectionHeader.SectionData.Text = "This is Header.";
sectionHeader.SectionData.Level = 3;

Section<SectionParagraphData> sectionParagraph1 = new Section<SectionParagraphData>();
sectionParagraph1.IsFocused = true;
sectionParagraph1.SectionData.Text = "This is Paragraph 1.";

Section<SectionParagraphData> sectionParagraph2 = new Section<SectionParagraphData>();
sectionParagraph2.SectionData.Text = "This is Paragraph 2.";

List<Section> sections = new List<Section>();
sections.Add(sectionHeader);
sections.Add(sectionParagraph1);
sections.Add(sectionParagraph2);
```

I am not able to LINQ and get element by `IsFocused == true`:

```
var focusedSection = sections.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsFocused == true);
```

Is possible to access the `SectionHeaderData` & `SectionParagraphData` members like in normal `List<SomeClass>` list?

**Edit 1:**

As advised, here is a little more information about what I need.

At some point of the program a function will be called in which I need to get the focused section and to be able to access more specific data of either `SectionHeaderData` OR `SectionParagraphData`.

For example, I will need to read / set the value of the `Text` property.

Comment: Basically you should move `Type` and `IsFocused` to the non-generic `Section` class. Then it should work fine. Only the `SectionData` property refers to `T`, so that's all that needs to be in the generic type.

Comment: Great! That worked like a charm @JonSkeet. But lets say that after I have the focused section I need to access specific data related to the ```SectionHeaderData & SectionParagraphData```. Would that be possible to be done?

Comment: @imb13 Use `.OfType<Section<SectionHeaderData>>()` to filter to objects of that particular type. THen you can reference properties of those types.

Comment: Then you'd need to cast it to the appropriate type. Or you *could* have an `abstract object SectionData { get; }` property in `Section`, if you didn't need strongly-typed access to it. Basically we're guessing at what you need at the moment - please edit the question with more details.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, please see my 'Edit 1'. Will try to implement the ```abstract object SectionData { get; }``` approach and see how it will go.

Comment: I suspect you want your `SectionHeaderData` and `SectionParagraphData` to both inherit from a `SectionData` class that has a `Text` property. Then you can just cast to `SectionData` (or make the property in the non-generic class just `SectionData` and constrain `T` accordingly).

Comment: Appreciate the help @JonSkeet, I will go with the "... to both inherit from a ```SectionData``` class that has a ```Text``` property" approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the properties into the abstract class:

```
public abstract class Section
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public bool IsFocused { get; set; }
}
```

> For example, I will need to read / set the value of the Text property.

I actually wondered why you would not pull the `Text` property into a base class and solve it with inheritance (I will steal the name from Jon Skeets comment):

```
public class SectionData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class SectionHeaderData : SectionData
{
    public int Level { get; set; }
}

public class SectionParagraphData: SectionData { }
```

then you can access those fields like this:

```
var textSection = sections.OfType<SectionData>().ToList();
textSection[0].Text = "this compiles";
```

Comment: Thanks, that absolutely worked. I still need a bit of help. Could you see my updated question please?

Comment: @imb13 I edited my answer to incorporate the second problem that you wrote in your edit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.